# Almost Surely Convergence of a Series of Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, random-variables

I am trying to solve this problem:

> Let $(X_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of independent random
> variables on the probability space $(\Omega , \mathcal{F},
>  \mathbb{P})$ and they all have uniform distribution on $[0,1]$.
>
> 1. Calculate $E(X_1 \cdots X_n)$ for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$.
> 2. Deduce that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_1\cdots X_n$ converges almost surely to a finite sum.

These are my thoughts on the first question:

Let $f(x)$ be the density function of uniform distribution on $[0,1]$. Then
$$E(X_1\cdots X_n) = \int_0^1 \cdots \int_0^1 x_1\cdots x_nf(x_1)\cdots f(x_n)dx_1\cdots dx_n.$$
Now, since $f(x)=1$ for $x\in [0,1]$ and by Fubini-Tonelli theorem we have
$$E(X_1\cdots X_n) = \int_0^1 x_1dx_1 \cdots \int_0^1x_ndx_n = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n.$$

For the second part, I defined
$$Y_n := X_1\cdots X_n.$$
Since the expectation of $Y_n$'s converges to $0$, we say that their outcomes go to zero on average. Hence it makes sense if we can find some constant $c\in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty Y_n = c\right) = 1.$$
But I do not know how can I prove the existence of the constant $c$ mathematically. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument for the computation of the expectation is fine. However, for the convergence of the series, your reasoning does not work. Having $\mathbb E[Y_n]\to 0$ does not mean that $\sum_{n\geqslant 1}Y_n$ converges (for example if $Y_n=1/n$ almost surely). Moreover, even if $\sum_{n\geqslant 1}Y_n$ converges, we are not sure at all whether this should be constant.

Instead, we can proceed as follows: let $Z_N=\sum_{n=1}^NY_n$. Then $(Z_N)_{N\geqslant 1}$ is a sequence of non-negative random variables and $Z_{N}\leqslant Z_{N+1}$ almost surely hence $Z_N\to Z$ and the monotone convergence theorem combined with the first part shows that $Z$ is integrable hence almost surely finite.

Comment: Why $Z_N \leq Z_{N+1}$ almost surely? By definition of $Z_N$ and by $X_n$'s being positive, $Z_N \leq Z_{N+1}$ at every point. Am I right? Another question: $Z_n$'s are measurable functions and we define $Z$ as its pointwise limit. So $Z$ is a measurable function and also a random variable. Right?

Comment: Can we say that $E(Z_n) \to E(Z)$ and conclude that $E(Z) = 1$? Then we can use Markov's inequality and say $Z$ is almost everywhere finite.

Comment: @Masoud Usually random variables are defined up to sets of measure $0$. Indeed $Z$ is measurable as a pointwise limit of measurable functions. I agree with the argument of the second comment.